# Connecting Azure Mobile Service database to Excel

Tags: excel, azure-mobile-services

I have a Windows Store app that uses Azure Mobile Services backend.  I want to be able to do some analysis on the data in my database tables for which I need to import that data into Excel.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a walk through of using Excel to access your Mobile Services data here: http://thejoyofcode.com/Using_excel_to_access_your_Mobile_Services_data.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options. First, the data in the Azure Mobile Services is stored in a "regular" SQL Azure database. So you can connect to it using a tool such as SQL Server Management Studio, and export the data.

Another option would be to save the data locally using the Command-Line Interface (CLI). [This document on MSDN](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/command-line-administration/) talks about using the CLI for administration of mobile services. The CLI also has options to read data from tables, so you can use that as well - but the result will not be on an Excel-compatible format. it supports both a text-based format and JSON; you'll likely want the JSON option which is easier to parse and create some Excel-friendly format such as CSV.